Warehouse, supply chain, cheating prevention
Warehouse & how it fills
Assume there is a warehouse with some employees to do the shopping. They:

Go around the market and research the supplies/sellers
Negotiate the price
Pay the money
Buy the supplies
Fill the warehouse

Software required
Focus on fraudulent activities
Now, this software is needed:

A software to prevent the shopping employees from cheating.
The software makes sure the shopping employees report the true correct payments.

It makes sure they are not exaggerating the payments and keeping the difference for themselves.


The software architecture might possibly consist of the following, if necessary:

Some smartphone apps installed on shopping employees phones.
Some desktop apps on the computers of the warehouse.
Some servers.
Anything else that is possibly needed.



Question
Is such a software available? Opensource or proprietary.
(by the way if there is a specific term for such software, please let me know)
